# How to customize a landing page ("Blocked by Netgear" - change to "Blocked by house owner", etc.)

Tags: html, css, block, customization

I hope I am in the right forum.

I just wanted to ask if I can customize a landing page.

I'm blocking some websites here in my house (my flatmates have been downloading dodgy stuff).

But instead of it saying "Blocked by Netgear", I want it to say something else "Landlord prohibits access to these websites as per the lease agreement" etc.

I'm using a Netgear DGN2200 Modem Router.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't think it's possible without going through a bit of hardwork:

See this forum for more info:
[Netgear Forum](http://forum1.netgear.com/showthread.php?t=18942)

Edit: From post above

> How To Change "BLOCKED BY NETGEAR FIREWALL"
>
> 1. Enable Debug Mode On Your Router   a) http://192.168.0.1/setup.cgi?todo=debug  b)
>      http://192.168.0.1/block.htm  c) view source of block.htm, copy it to
>      notepad, edit to your liking.     d) save modified block.htm as block.htm
>      to your C:\ as c:\block.htm
> 2. Open up a telnet console   a) telnet 192.168.0.1   b) enter your router username   c) enter your router password
> 3. Navigate/Change/CHMOD  a) cd /etc/     b) CHMOD 0777 block.htm     c) mv block.htm old_block.htm
> 4. Upload     a) open an FTP command line     b) upload c:\block.htm to your server   c) make sure it looks nice (NOTE: Angelfire/Geocities/etc...
>      will not work, banners ruin it)
> 5. SECRET WGET in Router  a) navigate to /etc/ in your router from telnet     b) wget http://yourpaidwebhost.com/block.htm    c) enjoy
> 6. Visit a blocked website    a) visit a blocked website.
>
> By Ryan M For GovernmentSecurity.org

Comment: Hi there, Thank you so much! I'm going to give this a go this weekend and will let everyone know the outcome. I'm sure there are other users out there who are curious about this issue.